# how to append a list on another page html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html page has a list of people's names, with a button at the bottom that says 'Add new'. On clicking this button, a pop up page opens. This page has a form to collect a new name. I want to add this name to the original list. This is my javascript which works perfectly to append a list on the same page as the text box:

```
<script>
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var text = $('#input').val();
        if (text.length){        
            $('ul.list-group').append('<li class="list-group-item">' +text+'</li>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

How can I edit it so that it appends the list on the original page?

Comment: You say you want to append the list to both a `popup` and a `different page`. These are very different things. Can you clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: are these jQuery mobile pages? page within main page? Not clear at all what you want

Comment: My html page has a list of people's names, with a button at the bottom that says 'Add new'. On clicking this button, a pop up page opens. This page has a form to collect a new name. I want to add this name to the original list! Does that make sense?

Comment: use cookies if you are not using server side session. Usually when the form is submit the value is stored in session and on reloading page you can access the value stored in session same as cookies. But if you are not reloading the original page then instead of using popup use dialog box (modal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of popup do you use ? With a classical popup (ie a "new page"), you can't do this with Javascript because it requires server-side treatment (Javascript is only for client, and so can only play with the current page DOM)

However, you can use something like [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), that is just a "popup-like" append to the DOM ; then you can easily modify your first list. ;)

Comment: I've just been using a classic popup, but the bootstrap one looks good. Could you give me a few pointers on how to use it? Does the code behind the modal go on the same html page as  my first list?

Comment: The code goes the same page yep ; read the page I link in my answer, it's pretty well explained ;)

Comment: It is pretty well explained, jumped the gun a bit before commenting! I can't seem to figure out the javascript though- I've taken the sample code and applied the bootstrap.min css, but when I click on the button nothing pops up?

Comment: Did you also add Bootstrap javascript ? ;)

Comment: Yes, just figured out I had to do that, thanks for the help :-)